# CGRectMake in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

I am using CGRectMake to produce a label and a textField inside of a UITableViewCell. Here is the code:

```
   label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 10, 0, 20)];
   label.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];      

   textField =
     [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 10, 0, 20)];
   textField.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

  [textField setDelegate:self]; // set the delegate to this object
  [textField addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDidEndOnExit)
      forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit];

  [self.contentView addSubview:label]; // add label to the cell
  [self.contentView addSubview:textField]; // add textField to cell
```

First, my understanding is the the parameters are defined as

```
  CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)
```

What I see in the cell is a label on the left with the textField immediately to its right. There is a small space between the two.

I would expect the X,Y coordinates to be relative to a 0,0 point in the upper left of the cell, with positive values going down and to the right.

I am confused by what I see.

I see that the label is located starting at the left of my cell, but it has an X value greater than the X value of the textField. The textField starts to the right of the label.

I don't understand why the width value for each is set to 0 (zero).

Also, what makes the textField take a position relative to the label, rather than relative to the cell coordinates.

Here is a simple sketch of the cell and what I see in it (with the background colors set, I can clearly see where the CGRects are being placed):

```
0,0---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                                                                                   |
|   ----------------    -----------------------------------------------------------------
|  |                |  |    
|  |  label         |  |   textField 
|  |                |  |    
|   ----------------    -----------------------------------------------------------------
|                                                                                   |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I also notice that the width of each label varies according to its content length. I understand this, but I don't understand why the textField moves around, staying the same distance from the label in each case.

[edit] By the way, "self" is a subclass of UITableViewCell, if I didn't make that clear.

Comment: I think you mean `[cell.contentView addSubview:label];` instead isn't it.

Comment: Why do you say you don't understand why the width for each is set to 0 when you are the one who set both wide to 0? Try set it to a non-zero value and update.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[image]

Comment: i think now you can understand the concept of tableview

Comment: The question is not about tableView.  The question is about the behavior of CGRectMake. My example is referring to a UITableViewCell, but I think that's probably irrelevant. The main questions are why is the width set to zero (what is that supposed to do)?  And why is the position of the label on the left when its x value is greater than the x value of the textField?

Comment: why you set the width to 0? if you set it to 0. the answer will not come like this. just a line will come.

Comment: then the x and y coordinates starts below the navigation bar only.. if you want to add buttons or labels in navigation bar means you have see UINavigationItem... http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationItem_Class/Reference/UINavigationItem.html

Comment: I have come a long way since April and i understand this a lot better. All of the positioning was done by additional code in the app I was referring to, but I didn't see it when I asked the question. The CGRectMake works exactly as it is described in the docs, and there is no more mystery.

Answer (score 0):

In a table view the labels and the textboxes print below the navigation bar. more clearly below the tab bar only it starts couting the x and y values. that is below tar bar it points (0,0)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. There is no tab bar mentioned in my example. (The tab bar would be at the bottom of the screen, below everything else, if there was one.) Thanks for trying.